# Trouble getting MapsV2/pager to work

Tags: android, commonsware

I having trouble with getting the MapsV2/Pager project to even compile.  (using 5.0 pdf
)

I start out with a new workspace.

Create new actionbarsherlock project from existing code. (have used this with success in other projects)

Create new Google-play-services_lib project from existing code. (have used this with success in other projects)

Create new MapV2Pager project from existing code.

Make and put new API key in MapV2Pager manifest.

Add the two library projects in Android properties and set build target to 2.3.3 (target all my apps to this)

I clean build everything and I get the following in the console window...

> xml:4: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar'. [2013-08-17
>   16:30:14 - MapsV2Pager]
>   D:\NewCWareWorkspace\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs_*styles.xml:6:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.Solid'.
>   [2013-08-17 16:30:14 - MapsV2Pager]
>   D:\NewCWareWorkspace\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs*_styles.xml:8:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar'.
>   [2013-08-17 16:30:14 - MapsV2Pager]
>   D:\NewCWareWorkspace\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs_*styles.xml:10:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid'.
>   [2013-08-17 16:30:14 - MapsV2Pager]
>   D:\NewCWareWorkspace\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs*_styles.xml:12:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse'. [2013-08-17
>   16:30:14 - MapsV2Pager]
>   D:\NewCWareWorkspace\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs_*styles.xml:15:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView'.
>   [2013-08-17 16:30:14 - MapsV2Pager]
>   D:\NewCWareWorkspace\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs*_styles.xml:17:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
>   [2013-08-17 16:30:14 - MapsV2Pager]
>   D:\NewCWareWorkspace\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs_*styles.xml:19:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView.Inverse'. [2013-08-17
>   16:30:14 - MapsV2Pager]
>   D:\NewCWareWorkspace\actionbarsherlock\res\values\abs*_styles.xml:89:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'android:dividerPadding'. [2013-08-17 16:30:14 - MapsV2Pager]
>   D:\NewCWareWorkspace\actionbarsherlock\res\values\abs_*styles.xml:88:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'android:showDividers'. [2013-08-17 16:30:14 - MapsV2Pager]
>   D:\NewCWareWorkspace\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs*_styles.xml:22:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabBar'.
>   [2013-08-17 16:30:14 - MapsV2Pager]
>   D:\NewCWareWorkspace\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs_*styles.xml:24:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabBar'.
>   [2013-08-17 16:30:14 - MapsV2Pager]
>   D:\NewCWareWorkspace\actionbarsherlock\res\values-v14\abs*_styles.xml:26:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabBar.Inverse'. [2013-08-17
>   16:30:14 - MapsV2Pager]
>   D:\NewCWareWorkspace\actionbarsherlock\res\values\abs__styles.xml:101:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'android:textAllCaps'.

I actually get much more that is pasted above.  It's complaining about the entries in the styles file in the actionbarsherlock library but I don't now why.  I have Googled all over on these errors but can't find anything that will work.

The console errors are likely the cause for R.Java not to build in MapsV2Pager hence it won't compile.

What could I be doing wrong?
Thanks, Gary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and set build target to 2.3.3 (target all my apps to this)

That will not work. Projects using ActionBarSherlock will need something higher, both for ActionBarSherlock's own project and for the app using it.

ActionBarSherlock was written [with API Level 14 as a build target](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/actionbarsherlock/project.properties).

`MapsV2/Pager` was written [with API Level 17 as a build target](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/MapsV2/Pager/project.properties); that or later will definitely work. It should work with API Level 14 or higher, IIRC.

Your `android:minSdkVersion` can be 10 (Android 2.3.3) if you want.